# Python - how can i take distinct pairs in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, compare

user input number of candies, and amount of money he has.

then user input the prices of each candy in an array.

i want to see how many distinct pairs of candies the user can buy which sum = the money the user has

example money: 5
examples prices: (1 2 3 4 5 7 7)
I can get (1, 4) (2, 3)
so i will increase "count" by 2, then distinct pairs = 2

My problem is.... I don't want to use (4, 1) and (3, 2) as i already used them but in reverse (1, 4), (2, 3). im facing a problem coding this part.
how can i compare the indices so i take them only once. i hope that makes sense.

here is my code:

```
numOfCandies, money = map(int, input().split())
price = list(map(int, input().split()))
arr = []
count = 0

for x in range(0, len(price)):
    arr.append(price[x])

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    for j in range(0, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] + arr[j] == money:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

The output is: 4
because its taking indices (0, 3) (1, 3) (3, 0) (3, 1)
I want to skip the last 2 pairs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
...
print(count/2)
```

Or in **hard** way:

1. Sort each pair
2. Sort all list
3. Remove dublicates
4. Print len of pairs

```py
import itertools

numOfCandies, money = map(int, input().split())
price = list(map(int, input().split()))
arr = []
count = 0

for x in range(0, len(price)):
    arr.append(price[x])

somepair = []
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    for j in range(0, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] + arr[j] == money:
            somepair.append([arr[i], arr[j]])
for i in range(len(somepair)):
    somepair[i].sort()
somepair.sort()
somepair = list(somepair for somepair,_ in itertools.groupby(somepair))

print(len(somepair))
```